# android studio analyzer doesn't see external headers (native opencv)

Tags: android-studio

Though it perfectly compiles (`CMakeFiles.txt` contains proper `include_directories`), in editor I have "not found" for opencv2 at

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

and name resolution and completion doesn't work of course, marking them "can't resolve".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems include_directories absolute path doesn't work for editor at least on windows - relative path from the project folder macro made the trick...